# Android source compile character string encoding

Tags: android, encoding

I want to compare the two national language and check whether they are consistent.

```
String language = loc.locale.getDisplayLanguage(loc.locale);  // loc is a JavaBean，locale is a java.util.Locale instance
if ("Čeština".trim().equalsIgnoreCase(language.trim())) {   // make compilation is not equal
      language = "Česky";
}
```

I compile in Eclipse. The If expression’s result is true. But in the source code by make compilation, the condition is false. I convert to utf-8 format to compare, it can not.

Now I ask for the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make some test output to see what the strings are. Seems they really are not equal.

Comment: This way you can do it reliably, because you ask display language in current locale `loc.locale` (which is variable), and compare this with a string in constant locale ("Čeština").